# ssh - Can't login

Tags: ssh

i use rsa key for login but not work.

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.8.102 [192.168.8.102] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file ubuntu_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file ubuntu_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.8.102:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:RxcfeiGRL58JwAlemi9oi0pFMNKAA3jWGu6H+DmzjGk
debug1: Host '192.168.8.102' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ubuntu_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

sshd_config

```
    # Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

perm :

```
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Jul 30 07:30 .ssh


-rw------- 1 user user  397 Jul 30 07:29 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 user user    0 Jul 30 04:23 known_hosts
```

Comment: The key is rejected by the server. Is the public key correctly set up on the server? How did you do that? What are the permissions of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and its parent directories on the server?

Comment: perm for .ssh is 700 , perm authorized_keys 644

Answer (score 1):

> perm for .ssh is 700 , perm authorized_keys 644 – Ali firouzbakhsh 1 min ago

The `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` can not be writable by anyone else as mentioned in the manual page for `sshd`:

> `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
>
> Lists the public keys (DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519, RSA) that can be used for logging in as this user.  The format of this file is described above.  The content of the file is not highly sensitive, but the recommended permissions are read/write for the user, and not accessible by others.
>
> **If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home directory are writable by other users, then the file could be modified or replaced by unauthorized users**.  In this case, sshd will not allow it to be used unless the StrictModes option has been set to “no”.

Change the permissions to `600`:

```
chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

They also need to be owned by the user, not by root:

```
chown user:user /home/user/.ssh/ /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: tnx , changed permision :) but i have problem in login

Comment: wut? Did it fix the problem or not? If not, can you get the debug log from the server and edit the question with it?

Comment: edit log and add permision detail in end of file

Comment: You are connecting as a `user`, but both directory and `authorized_keys` is owned by root (if you are looking at the correct file). Make sure that both of them are owned by the user who is connecting (already part of the quote in the answer).

Comment: sorry , i use  ' sudo -s ' , now change all and edit question ... you need adds public key in question ?